# From a SUM aggregrate trying to extract only the max value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sum, max

/* THIS WORKS - Shows yesterday’s hourly sessions for all prod servers */

```
SELECT
SUM(active_sessions_peak + inactive_sessions_peak) 
AS TotalSessions, machine_name, time_stamp
FROM  ctrx_archive_system_perf
WHERE machine_name LIKE 'vmw-mc-%p%'
GROUP BY machine_name, time_stamp
ORDER BY machine_name
```

/* THIS ALSO WORKS - Only returns midnight's values per server */

```
SELECT
SUM(active_sessions_peak + inactive_sessions_peak) 
AS TotalSessions, machine_name, time_stamp
FROM   vw_ctrx_archive_system_perf
WHERE machine_name LIKE 'vmw-mc-%p%'
AND 
time_stamp = CAST(DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE) 
GROUP BY machine_name, time_stamp
ORDER BY machine_name
```

That last one gives me the TotalSessions for each server but only the midnight one. Throughout the day those session numbers of course change. What I am seeking is the max, the highest reported number for that day for each machine_name. I researched getting the MAX from a SUM and tried a temp table as well as a sub-query but cannot get either approach  to work.

Comment: And for **what database system** is this? SQL is just the query language - used by many databases, like MySQL, Postgres, IBM DB2, Oracle, SQL Server, and many many more. Please specify your concrete database you're using as a tag to your question.

Comment: You probably want to use window functions. The extent to which these are supported depends on the database system and version.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your attempt at using a subquery and the details of how it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(TotalSessions) as MaxSessions, machine_name
FROM (
  SELECT
  SUM(active_sessions_peak + inactive_sessions_peak) 
  AS TotalSessions, machine_name, time_stamp
  FROM  ctrx_archive_system_perf
  WHERE machine_name LIKE 'vmw-mc-%p%'
  GROUP BY machine_name, time_stamp
) AS machine_sums
GROUP BY machine_name
ORDER BY machine_name
```

Which should work in any database which understands SQL. If you need to get the associated timestamp as well, things get more difficult.

Comment: Man that was fast. And I'm thrilled it did not error out. But I cannot fathom what day or time period I'm looking at as only MaxSessions and Machine_Name are returned. 

In your suggestion the WHERE clause that casts the date and gets yesterday's date is omitted: time_stamp = CAST(DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE) ) 

I'm guessing that was intentional as you did mention some challenge fro getting time_stamp.

Comment: Yeah, I need time_stamp or some way to verify the results are from yesterday (or today or whenever for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte1 as
    select
        sum(active_sessions_peak + inactive_sessions_peak) as TotalSessions,
        machine_name,
        time_stamp
    from ctrx_archive_system_perf
    where machine_name LIKE 'vmw-mc-%p%'
    group by machine_name, time_stamp
), cte2 as (
    select
        row_number() over (partition by machine_name order by TotalSessions desc) as row_num,
        *
    from cte1 
)
select
    TotalSessions, machine_name, time_stamp
from cte2
where row_num = 1
```